# full width svg random whitespace issue

Tags: html, svg, whitespace

I'm using SVGs to separate full width sections on my page and I've come across this issue with SVGs where at some resolutions, the shape in the svg is offset by a couple of pixels either on the sides or the bottom.

[image: example 1]
[image: example 2]

In some browsers and some resolutions this is not happening at all. Firefox doesn't seem to be affected by this at all. However it's especially pronounced in Android (4.4.4) and Chrome (38.0.2125.114). Seems to be a webkit/blink issue.

The SVG I'm using:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="my-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 1920 185">
    <path d="M0,185L1680,5c0,0,50-10,80,0s50,20,50,20l110,70v90"/>
  </svg>
```

I've tried working around this with margins, but then it also affects the resolutions that are fine, which now have undesired sharp corners.

Any idea what is causing this offset? Any suggestions for a workaround/fix?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us this SVG embedded in a minimal HTML file that exhibits this behaviour? Problems like this are often caused by SVGs with non-integer dimensions; in your case it may be the HTML parent object that has non-integer dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. Your `viewBox` attribute is spelled wrong. `viewbox` is not a valid attribute name.
2. If that doesn't help, try adding `preserveAspectRatio="none"` after your `viewBox` attribute.  It may help ameliorate any pixel rounding issues.

Comment: Cheers, the preserveAspectRatio seemed to fix it. At least in Chrome, the misspelled viewBox didn't seem to affect this issue.